# Is there a way in python to store imports inside a module and then run said module to load packages?

Tags: python

Is there a way I can store my import packages inside a module and then run said module to load the packages? Something like below:

```
# Store imports in a module
def LoadPackages():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    ...

# Run module to load packages
LoadPackages()
```

I tried this and I got the below error:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Importing shouldn't be a headache. Does your source have one main file that imports everything it needs, and declare classes where needed in your own code?

Comment: It fail because import are defined only in your function scope here in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable names as `global` in the function and the imports will be bound to variable names in the module's global scope.

```
>>> def LoadPackages():
...     global pd, np
...     import pandas as pd
...     import numpy as np
... 
>>> pd.DataFrame()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
>>>
>>>
>>> LoadPackages()
>>> pd.DataFrame
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>>
```

Comment: I should have thought of that! I have come across the global function before. This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can have another python file called "modules.py" and inside that file you can add

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Then in your other python file all you will need to do is import that initial file using

```
import modules
```

of course the drawback here is you will always need to call all functions or objects using `modules.pd.etc` so it would be best to use

```
from modules import pd, np, #rest of modules
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just have a file called `modules.py`, and inside it you put your imports. Then you import it like this in your other files:

```py
from module import *
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is only imported if and only if the function is executed.
If you may only run a function very rarely and don't need the module imported anywhere else, it may be beneficial to only import it in that function. Or if there is a name clash or other reason you don't want the module or symbols from the module available everywhere, you may only want to import it in a specific function

for example:

```
def LoadPackages():
    import requests
    res = requests.get("https://google.com")
    print(res)

LoadPackages()

res = requests.get("https://google.com")
```

Output is:

```
**<Response [200]>**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-b435c28bc51c> in <module>
      1 LoadPackages()
      2
----> 3 res = requests.get("https://google.com")

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Here **requests** library is imported inside the function scope and successfully performed the "GET" request. And when I made the "GET" request outside function I get the import error.